# Custom file extensions works in File Explorer but not browsers

Tags: c#, browser, mime-types

I want a C# winforms app that I have written to digest a pdf file automatically... so, I have registered the type .webprintpdf in my setup installer program. And... I have renamed a file named test.pdf to test.webprintpdf... when I double click on the file in File Explorer... it is opened by my app automatically.

However in my html I have this code...

```
<script language="JavaScript">window.location.href = 'test.webprintpdf';</script>
```

Note: the mimetype is set to "application/octet-stream" for this file.

All of the browsers download the file... but none of them want to open it using my app.

With Firefox and Chrome it defaults to save... and when I try to open it, my app doesn't show in the list of possible "helper" applications... but if I browse to my executable it works fine. In both cases, however, "Save as Default" is either disabled or not available.

In IE... the text of the file just shows up in the browser window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the document to open up external to the browser, you need to set the following header:

```
content-disposition: attachment; filename=xxx.webprintpdf
```

Otherwise the browser will try to handle the document inline.

Also, be sure your headers allow caching of the content (i.e. do ***not*** set `HttpCacheability.NoCache`) or else the browser will always display a Save As dialog since it can't cache the file to open it in the app.